# Writing data in to influxDB

Tags: python, linux, influxdb, gpio

I am trying to write the data that I'm reading from my DHT11 sensor, which is connected to my GPIO, into my InfluxDB container database. I have written my own library, and I am able to establish a connection to my database. However, I am encountering difficulties in writing data into the database.

my Library:

```
# socket-Module werden für die Netzwerkkommunikation importiert
import socket

# Das sys-Modul wird für die Systemfunktionen importiert
import sys

class InfluxDB_Bibliothek:
        def __init__(self, host, port, database):
                self.host = host                                                                # Die Host-Adresse
                self.port = port                                                                # Der Port, auf der die DB läuft
                self.database = database                                                        # Die Datenbank, in der die Daten geschrieben werden
                self.socket = None                                                              # Socket-Objekt Initalisieren

        def Verbinden(self):
                self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 # Eine Socket-Objekt wird für die Kommunikation erstellt
                try:
                        self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))                             # Verbindung zum Host
                        print("Verbindung erfolgreich hergestellt")

                except socket.error as e:
                        print("Verbindung zur Datenbank fehlgeschlagen", e)                     # Wenn keine´Verbindung hergestellt wird, error ausgeben
                        sys.exit(1)                                                             # Das Programm wird bei einem Fehler beendet

        def Schreiben(self, measurement, fields):
                data = "INSERT {} {}\n" .format(measurement, fields)                            # Eine Datenpunkt zum schreiben der Daten wir erstellt
                self.Senden(data)                                                                       # Die daten senden

        def Anfrage(self, anfrage_string):
                data = "QUERY {}\n" .format(anfrage_string)                                     # Eine Query-Anfrage für die Datenbank erstellen
                antwort = self.Senden(data)                                                     # Eine Query-Anfrage an die Datenbank senden
                return antwort                                                                  # Die Antwort zurück geben

        def Senden(self, data):
                try:
                        self.socket.sendall(data.encode())                                      # Die Daten über das Socket-Objekt was erzeugt wurde senden
                        antwort = self.socket.recv(1024)
                        return antwort.decode()                                                 # Die Antwort wird dekodiert und zurück gegeben
                except socket.error as e:
                        print("Fehler beim Senden von Daten an die Datenbank")                  # Wenn beim senden ein Fehler gibt, eine Fehlermeldung ausgeben
                        sys.exit(1)                                                             # Das Programm wir bei einem Fehler beendet

        def Schließen(self):
                self.socket.close()                                                             # Das Socket-Objekt wird geschlossen
```

And this is the part of my code where I'm using my library to write the data into my database.

```
# Eine Instanz zur Datenbankklasse erstellen
Datenbank = influxdb.InfluxDB_Bibliothek(database = "Sensor", host = "Container/localhost-IP", port = 8086)

try:

        Datenbank.Verbinden()                   # Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen

        while True:
                # Temperatur und Luftfeuchte auslesen
                temperature = dht_device.temperature
                humidity  = dht_device.humidity

                # Hier werden die Daten, die vom Sensor ausgelesen werden, in der Datenank geschrieben
                Datenbank.Schreiben(measurement = "Sensor_Daten", fields = {"Temperatur": temperature, "Luftfeuchtigkeit": humidity})



                # 2 Sekunden pause, bevor die Werte erneut ausgelesen werden
                time.sleep(2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Mit (Strg + C), das Programm beenden

        pass
finally:

        Datenbank.Schließen()                           # Die Verbindung zur Datenbank wird geschlossen

        # Sensor schließen und alle GPIO-Pins frei machen
        dht_device.exit()
```

Comment: Please give a more detailed problem description than "encountering difficulties".

Comment: My problem is that I cannot write data to the database. In my library, in the "Senden" method, the data is sent via a socket object that is created. The socket object is created in the "Verbinden" method. I get [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Add the full error traceback *to the question*.

Comment: A word on style: "Denglisch" is not going to help you (in the long run) and non-German speakers (for the sake of getting an answer to your question). Hint: Make it as easy as possible for others to understand your question and the likelihood of getting a (good) answer gets a whole lot bigger.